# class string array property cannot be read

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2013.

I have a class called clsFund. It has one property of type string() called CompanyNames.

```
 private pCoName() as string

 Public Property Get CompanyNames() As String()
    CompanyNames = pCoName
 End Property
```

In a standard module I try to retrieve this string array but without any luck. I have the code below. The funny thing is the ubound tells me the correct answer of 10 but it doesn't like the line below clsData.PnL, the method is just expecting a string argument which I belive I have supplied however I get a compile error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment - I do not understand?

```
 Private Sub PrintCompanyNameAndPnL()

 Dim i As Integer

 For i = 1 To UBound(Fund.BloombergIndices)
     Range("A" & i) = clsData.PnL(Fund.CompanyNames(i))                    
 Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write it that way, you are passing `i` as a parameter to the `CompanyNames` property, which doesn't accept any arguments.

You need to access the array items like this:

```
Range("A" & i) = clsData.PnL(Fund.CompanyNames()(i))
```

so you are returning the array and then passing `i` as an index to that.

Answer (score 1):

You return a full array, so you need an extra set of parens to address the elements:

```
Range("A" & i) = clsData.PnL(Fund.CompanyNames()(i))
```

Or change to

```
Public Property Get CompanyName(index As Integer) As String
   CompanyName = pCoName(index)
End Property
```